# Define NFA for the following languages

Tags: automata

**Question:**

> Define NFA for the following languages :
>
> 1. $L_1=\{\sigma w \sigma\big| \sigma\in\{a,b,c\},w\in\{a,b,c\}^*\}$
> 2. $L_n=\{w\in\{0,1\}^* \big| the \ n^{th} \ from  \ last \ char\  is\ 1\}$

---

$Solution.A.$ we define NFA for $L_1$. Let $$A=( Q,\Sigma ,q_{0} ,\delta ,F)$$such that,$$ \begin{array}{l}
Q=\{q_{0} ,q_{1} ,q_{2}\}\\
\Sigma =\{a,b,c\}\\
F=\{q_{2}\}
\end{array}$$
and let $\displaystyle \delta :( Q\times \Sigma )\rightarrow \mathcal{P}( Q)$ the transition function such that: $$\forall \sigma \in \Sigma :\delta (\{q_{0}\} ,\sigma ) =\{q_{1}\} \land \delta (\{q_{2}\} ,\sigma ) =\{q_{1} ,q_{2}\} \land \delta ( q_{2} ,\Sigma \backslash \{\sigma \}) =\{q_{1}\}$$
$Solution.B. $ we define NFA for $L_n$. Let $$A=( Q,\Sigma ,q_{0} ,\delta ,F)$$such that, $$ \begin{array}{l}
Q=\{q_{0} ,q_{1} ,q_{2} ,\dotsc ,q_{n}\}\\
\Sigma =\{0,1\}\\
F=\{q_{n}\}
\end{array}$$and let $\delta :( Q\times \Sigma )\rightarrow \mathcal{P}( Q)$
the transition function such that:$$ \begin{array}{l}
\delta (\{q_{0}\} ,0) =\{q_{0}\} \ \\
\delta (\{q_{0}\} ,1) =\{q_{0} ,q_{1}\}\\
\forall n\geq 2,i\in [ 2,n] :\delta (\{q_{i-1}\} ,\sigma ) =\{q_{i}\}
\end{array}$$

---

I am not sure whether I wrote the definition properly in terms of formally. Therefore, I will be glad to see what you think about it. Thanks!

Comment: Your Solution $A$ is conceptually wrong (it doesn't do what is supposed to do) and formally meaningless (the definition of $\delta(q_2,\Sigma\setminus\{\sigma\})$ is abstract nonsense: what does $\Sigma\setminus\{\sigma\}$ mean?). Note that $L_1$ is the language of the words over$\{a,b,c\}$ with at least two characters such that its first and the last characters are the same. Do you see how to fix your NFA?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco why is it wrong? I will be grateful if you can tell me what is wrong, and why what I wrote is nonsense because I really don't know how to define it properly. If it is conceptually wrong then what is the concept? In addition, what do you think about solution B?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco oh I see what you are telling me now, I thought about it. Solution A is wrong because I wrote in the function a group of 2 chars, and $\delta$ only accepts one. Right?

Comment: It's hard to give you a more precise answer, because I don't understand the definition of $\delta(q_2,\Sigma\setminus\{\sigma\})$.  What does $\Sigma\setminus\{\sigma\}$ mean? What is the transition function $\delta$ supposed to do on the state $q_2$? More generally, what is the informal and intuitive definition of your NFA for Solution $A$? If we first make your intuition clear, then we can formalize it properly. I suspect there are two kinds of error in your Solution $A$: at the informal level (what is your NFA is supposed to do) and at the formal level (how to formalize your intuition).

Comment: When you define the transition function $\delta$, you have to say how $\delta$ behaves with _every_ state and _every_ character. So, if your set of states is $\{q_0, q_1, q_2\}$ and your alphabet is $\{a,b,c\}$, you have to define $\delta(q_0, a) = \dots$, $\delta(q_0, b) = \dots$, $\delta(q_0, c) = \dots$, $\delta(q_1, a) = \dots$, $\delta(q_1, b) = \dots$, and so on. If $\delta(q_0, a) = \delta(q_0, b) = \delta(q_0, c)$, it makes sense to simply define $\delta(q_0, \sigma) = \dots$ (for any $\sigma \in \Sigma$), but writing $\delta(q_0, \Sigma\setminus\sigma) = \dots$ is abstract nonsense.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco right. Can I give it a fix and then can you see it and tell me whether it's good or not?

Comment: Sure! No problem. Hint: in Solution $A$ you need more than three states.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco I thought fixing it like this: $$\forall \sigma \in \Sigma \left[ \delta (\{q_{0}\} ,\sigma ) =\{q_{1}\} \land \delta (\{q_{2}\} ,\sigma ) =\{q_{1} ,q_{2}\} \land \forall \sigma ^{*} \in \Sigma \backslash \{\sigma \} :\delta \left( q_{2} ,\sigma ^{*}\right) =\{q_{1}\}\right]$$

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco or more accurate is to just simply make 3 states for each $\sigma \in \Sigma$?

Comment: What does $\sigma^* \in \Sigma \setminus \{\sigma\}$ mean? What do you want to say, informally? If you can provide a more explicit definition of the transition function $\delta$, in the style I sketched in a previous comment, I can at least understand your definition. Moreover, your definition of $\delta$ is incomplete, it doesn't say anything about the behavior of $\delta$ when its state argument is $q_1$.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco what do you say about it? $$ \begin{array}{l}
Q=\{q_{0} ,q_{1} ,q_{2} ,q_{3} ,q_{4}\}\\
\Sigma =\{a,b,c\}\\
F=\{q_{4}\}\\
\\
\\
\delta (\{q_{0}\} ,a) =\delta (\{q_{1}\} ,b) =\delta (\{q_{1}\} ,c) =\{q_{1}\}\\
\delta (\{q_{0}\} ,b) =\delta (\{q_{2}\} ,a) =\delta (\{q_{2}\} ,c) =\{q_{2}\}\\
\delta (\{q_{0}\} ,c) =\delta (\{q_{3}\} ,a) =\delta (\{q_{3}\} ,b) =\{q_{3}\}\\
\delta (\{q_{1}\} ,a) =\{q_{1} ,q_{4}\}\\
\delta (\{q_{2}\} ,b) =\{q_{2} ,q_{4}\}\\
\delta (\{q_{3}\} ,c) =\{q_{3} ,q_{4}\}
\end{array}$$

Comment: Great! Perfect, except for a formal mistake. The function $\delta$ is from $Q \times \Sigma$ to $\mathcal{P}(Q)$, so its first argument must be and element of $Q$ ($q_0$, or $q_1$, and so on) and not the singleton of an element of $Q$ ($\{q_0\}$, or $\{q_1\}$, and so on). For instance, $\delta(\{q_1\}, a) = \{q_1, q_4\}$ must be $\delta(q_1, a) = \{q_1, q_4\}$, and $\delta(\{q_0\},a) = δ(\{q_1\},b)=δ(\{q_1\},c) = \{q_1\}$ must be $\delta(q_0,a)=δ(q_1,b)=δ(q_1,c) = \{q_1\}$.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco oh you're right. Btw, what do you say about solution B? considering that I fixed the {} in delta

Comment: Your Solution $B$ is great! +1! Provided that you remove "$\{$" and "$\}$" from the first argument in the definition of the transition function $\delta$, and that $\sigma$ stands for any character in the alphabet $\Sigma$ in the last case of the definition of $\delta$.